ag-grid doesn't retain focus on switching between windows
I have used custom headerComponent for all columns and custom cellRenderer for all cells in ag-grid. When a particular cell or header has focus, if I switch to another window and come back to the ag-grid window, it doesn't retain focus. Focus goes to the first field of the window. How to make ag-grid retain focus when switching between windows?

A possible reason of that would be a redraw operation
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/view-refresh/#redraw-rows
You need to keep the last focused cell and set it manually after redraw operation like that
const focusedCell = this.gridApi.getFocusedCell();
this.gridApi.redrawRows();
if (focusedCell) {
  this.gridApi.setFocusedCell(focusedCell.rowIndex, focusedCell.column);
}

Read the discussion about this on https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/4661
Here's a plunker for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/zyCt7wZaJ9FA7inZ?preview
